# Flexslider vertical aligment to bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css, vertical-alignment, flexslider

**How to set the vertical alignment of a text within the [`flexslider`](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider) to the bottom, just above the page control elements?**

*See the example in the picture.*

[image: example]

It should be possible to set the inner `<div>` to:

```css
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

But that doesn't work as the `<li>...</li>` entry has not the full height. As the text length is dynamic there will by different heights and therefore the text should be always oriented to the bottom towards the page control.

The result should look like that:

[image: result example]

---

**Here a working code example:**

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    directionNav: false
  });
});
```

```css
.flexslider {
    width: 500px;
}

.flexslider ul, .flexslider ol {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

blockquote, q {
    font-size: 14px;
    quotes: "»" "«" "›" "‹";
}

p.quoted {
    font-size: 11px;
}

.flex-control-paging li {
    float: left;
    margin: 2px 4px 2px 0;
}

.flex-control-paging {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: -24px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
}

.flex-control-paging a::before {
    background-color: #b2b2b2;
    content: "";
    height: 3px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    width: 60px;
}

.flex-control-paging a {
    border: 0 none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    text-indent: -999em;
    width: 62px;
}

.flex-control-paging .flex-active::before, .flex-control-paging .flex-active:hover::before {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/master/jquery.flexslider-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li><div><q>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</q> <p class="quoted">Lorem ipsum</p></div></li>
    <li><div><q>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</q> <p class="quoted">Lorem ipsum</p></div></li>
    <li><div><q>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</q> <p class="quoted">Lorem ipsum</p></div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I deleted my answer since time ran away and I don't know flexslider well enough for a quick fix. Hopefully I can find more time later.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, hope you understood now what I try to achieve.

Comment: I got that, so when the slider start animate, the CSS rules I made in my sample gets overridden, which means I need to stick my head into `flexslider` to understand how it does that, so I can change the CSS accordingly (which take more time than I have right know) ... so likely some else might know this already and will give you an answer before I get some spare time

Comment: Will this help? https://www.drupal.org/node/2217999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `vertical-align` work if you set the element `display` property value to `inline-block`.

**E.g.**

```
/** need to remove the float since we are now using `inline-block` */
.flexslider ul.slides li {
      float: none !important; 
      display: inline-block !important;
      vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Now putting it to your current code :

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    directionNav: false
  });
});
```

```css
.flexslider {
    width: 500px;
}

.flexslider ul, .flexslider ol {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.flexslider ul.slides li {
  float: none !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

blockquote, q {
    font-size: 14px;
    quotes: "»" "«" "›" "‹";
}

p.quoted {
    font-size: 11px;
}

.flex-control-paging li {
    float: left;
    margin: 2px 4px 2px 0;
}

.flex-control-paging {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: -24px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
}

.flex-control-paging a::before {
    background-color: #b2b2b2;
    content: "";
    height: 3px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    width: 60px;
}

.flex-control-paging a {
    border: 0 none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    text-indent: -999em;
    width: 62px;
}

.flex-control-paging .flex-active::before, .flex-control-paging .flex-active:hover::before {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/master/jquery.flexslider-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li><div><q>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</q> <p class="quoted">Lorem ipsum</p></div></li>
    <li><div><q>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</q> <p class="quoted">Lorem ipsum</p></div></li>
    <li><div><q>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</q> <p class="quoted">Lorem ipsum</p></div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for the answer that's what I was looking for!

Comment: @wittich Cool! Glad it helped.